# scipy not compiling on Python 3.4

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, scipy

When importing scipy:

```
from scipy import signal
```

I get the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Desktop\Programming\Python\Sample Programs\src\butter.py", line 7, in <module>
  from scipy import signal
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 280, in <module>
  from .bsplines import *
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\bsplines.py", line 12, in <module>
  from scipy.special import comb, gamma
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 601, in <module>
  from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`
```

I am running Eclipse on windows 7.  I installed scipy successfully using

```
pip3.4 install "scipy-0.16.0rc1-cp34-none-win32.whl"
```

Can you tell me how I can get scipy to work with this simple program on Windows 7?

Comment: In general, compiling the scientific stack for Python is very difficult.  I recommend using a system like Anaconda where this has been done for you: http://continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned prior, the easiest way to get SciPy running on windows is to simply download the Anaconda distribution. Be sure to obtain the version you want. It works out of the box. Plus you get Jupyter/IPython Notebook which is a really cool interactive GUI interface. It's almost like working in Matlab!

http://continuum.io/downloads